# Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined in navLinks fullcalendar Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I'm integrating full-calendar from fullcalendar.io into my Angular project. I installed all required plugins such as dayGrid, timeGrid, interaction. I'm using navLinks here -> https://fullcalendar.io/docs/navLinks 
 also I saw same solve of problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7chhen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html, but here navLinks is working normally. 
MyCode
Html code ->

```
<full-calendar
    #calendar
    ...
    [navLinks]="true"
    (navLinkDayClick)="navLinkDayClick($event)"
    (navLinkWeekClick)="navLinkDayClick($event)"
></full-calendar>
```

in  Component class ->

```
...
calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin, timeGrigPlugin, interactionPlugin, bootstrap];
...
navLinkDayClick(date){
    console.log('day');
}

navLinkWeekClick(date){
    console.log('week');
}
```

this is error when clicking on date ->

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
    at options.<computed> (fullcalendar-angular.js:303)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (main.esm.js:6622)
    at HTMLElement.realHandler (main.esm.js:379)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:32819)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:465)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
    at HTMLElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone-evergreen.js:1629) defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:4799 handleError @ core.js:4851 next @ core.js:33552 schedulerFn @ core.js:29522
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183 next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72 next @ Subscriber.js:49 next @ Subject.js:39 emit @ core.js:29484 (anonymous) @ core.js:32877 invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359 run @ zone-evergreen.js:124 runOutsideAngular @ core.js:32764 onHandleError @ core.js:32874 handleError @ zone-evergreen.js:363 runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:171 invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:465 invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603 globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1629
```

also dependencies in package.json ->

```
"@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.3.1",
"@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
"@fullcalendar/core": "^4.3.1",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.3.0",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.3.0",
"@fullcalendar/list": "^4.3.0",
"@fullcalendar/luxon": "^4.3.0",
"@fullcalendar/moment": "^4.3.0",
"@fullcalendar/moment-timezone": "^4.3.0",
"@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.3.0",
```

module ->

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    FullCalendarModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
    UsersWorkCalendarComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
    UsersWorkCalendarComponent,
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Comment: Can you please share more details like your app.module and version details?

Comment: Have you add all dependencies for `full-calendar`  like `@fullcalendar/angular`, `@fullcalendar/core`  ..?

Comment: @DeC yes of course

Comment: @SiddharthPal yes.. now I will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the latest version error [github closed issue but reproducible in 4.3.1](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular/issues/232)

My suggestion is to downgrade to the 2.4.1 version that you are using in your stackblitz as this is a recurring bug (check the github issues and linked issues).

Comment: I downgrade all fullcalendar packages from 4.3 to 4.2 in my project.. and yes it's working... But navLinkDayClick and navLinkWeekClick are not working.. but any way, those functions are not needed.. I just need to navigate from month to day.. Thanks